# Why is there no option to downvote comments?

Tags: feature-request

Lately I have come across a number of q&a's where someone has made a comment that it's a possible 'duplicate', yet the q&a they refer to is not the first one found on Google, and in FACT not quite a duplicate. The comments therefore contribute zero to the post and seem to indicate the commentor does not understand the question nor the answer.

So my question is, why can we upvote, yet not downvote, a comment?

Comment: Because a downvote on a comment is useless. If the comment is wrong, post your own comment disputing it; that comment can then be upvoted.

Comment: because comments are supposed to be **temporary** - to request clarification or point out something that is wrong.

Comment: Comments are second class citizens.  Or so I'm told.

Comment: If that is the case then why an option to upvote a comment? I know I am being sticky here, but I feel some comments are just plain annoying. Easier to downvote than comment on, then concentrate on the actual problem at hand. Mebbe I am just too irritated today...

Comment: Filtering. If there are lots of comments, those that are upvoted will filter to the top and remain visible, while the rest is collapsed. And upvotes are sufficient for that.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments

Comment: @gnat, thanks for that. funny I did not see it typing the question. Anyways, apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: @GavinSimpson It's a "duplicate" on another network/site, so you wouldn't.

Comment: The problem as I see it with the current system is that is seems to me there are some who just love to search for , and then mark, questions as possible duplicates, and even worse sometimes the request get's approved. This for an answer that is not on the same topic as the question, therefore not correct, so I'd like to downvote it... to make me happy.

Comment: I find it ironic I just voted to close this. I hope it does not "contribute zero to the post".

Comment: Lol @dirkk. Not when you are right.

Comment: blah blah comments blah second-class citizens rant blah

Answer (score 4):

The answer for almost any feature request regarding adding more features to the comment system tends to be basically the same - overall, the Stack Exchange comment system is designed to be used as little as possible, and if any changes were going to be made, they'd be changes intended to encourage people to use comments LESS rather than making them a richer system. People aren't always happy when that means declining proposed enhancements, but the Stack Exchange goal is to focus on Q&A rather than encouraging discussion.

Comment: It is strange that a site that wants to focus on Q&A and not discussions would do this, eh?

Comment: I totally understand and agree with the position - I've just found lately that people try to debate me less on Meta if I express things in the most neutral tone possible. That said, I edited to make it sound less like I personally disagree.

Comment: I definitely agree with the goal of questions being answered. Getting downvoted in a comment will surely discourage,  'random' comments, would it not?

Comment: If the downvotes don't result in rep changes, why would it discourage anything? unless of course it would eventually lead to comment ban, which i don't see as being that useful unless someone was abusing the system.

Comment: Cos I am not so much concerned with the rep change or the commentor, but it would help not to waste time on any links provided if the comments has negative votes.